# Wall settling from water leak, poly foam injection or push piers?

Tags: blocking

I have a home built in 1976. It is 32'x 60'.  There are two 'beams' (3 sistered 2x10s) that span the 60'. The beams were supported by two sistered 2x6 every 8'to 10' on concrete pads. There is a 14x40' addition on the north side. The addition was slab on grade and attached to the side of the home.

We had a water leak in the crawl space. The wall with the addition was pulled about 1" on the top as the slab settled and broke apart. The tile in that room is cracked and uneven.

There is 36" in the crawlspace. How should I fix the slab on grade and the wall?

All my beautiful hickory hardwood floor are now bouncy. There was no blocking on the 2x8 joists. Should I sister the joist were they are bouncy? Or should I block or bridge?

Comment: I think you should have a structural engineer check this out.  You probably have more problems that simple blocking/sistering would fix.  An inch movement caused by a water leak is big.

Comment: It's kind of hard to visualize this on the info given.  Pictures would help if you are able to post them.